# Retrieve the query value into trigger body

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Let say you have the following two tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Photos 
(
    photoId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT(500) NOT NULL,
    visibilityId INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Comments 
(
    commentId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    comment TEXT(1000),
    photoId INT DEFAULT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (photoId) REFERENCES Photos (photoId) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

And as you can see there is a relation between them, since `comments.photoId` is a foreign key to the table `Photos`.

Someone tries to delete a photo that has a comment (let's say that photoId=1 has at least one comment):

```sql
DELETE FROM Photos 
WHERE photoId = 1
```

And let's say that no photo with comments can be deleted. I want to implement this rule with a trigger like here:

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER triggerCheckDeletePhoto
    BEFORE DELETE ON Photos
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      DECLARE comments INT;
      SET comments = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE comments.photoId=PhotoId_from_query);
      IF (comments > 0) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = 'A commented photo cannot be deleted';
      END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And the problem is, how do I retrieve that "photoId=1" inside the trigger. Something like `new.photoId` if this were a `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger.

I know that this could be implemented when defining the Foreign Key at the comment table, but the asked approach here will server other purposes where the foreign Key's one would not be possible. I am using MariaDB. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the problem is, how do I retrieve that "photoId=1"

Inside the trigger you want to retrieve the right photoId and 1 is only your example.

in your cas use : OLD.photoID (ie the actual one)